# XCode 6 iOS Swift - UIWebView size won't change

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uiwebview

I am currently trying some iOS programming. I decided to go with Swift.

Everything is going fine, untill I try to use a UIWebView it won't change it's size to the screen size. I started app development on Android, but afaik there is nothing like relative sizes in iOS right?

Currently this is what my code looks like:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainWebView: UIWebView!

var urlPath = "http://www.google.com"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    loadWebView()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loadWebView()
{
    var newRect = mainWebView.bounds

    newRect.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height
    newRect.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width

    mainWebView.frame.size = newRect.size

    let requestURL = NSURL(string:urlPath)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    mainWebView.loadRequest(request)
}

}
```

I tried different approaches with the above (giving de frame size to the mainWebView, but none work. Maybe it has something to do with the moment I give the commands to change size? Should I change the size earlier in the loading proces?

I also tried this:

```
mainWebView.sizeThatFits(self.view.frame.size)
```

But that didn't do anything either.

I would definitely appreciate all help!

Thanks in advance

Friso

PS.
In the example I am using the values from self.frame.size, but also when using for instance 100 x 100, it just won't change the size...

Comment: What constraints do you have set in Interface builder?

Comment: What is the size of `self.view` and `self. mainWebView` ? You assume that  `self.view` take all space on screen. Maybe it's not ?

Comment: @Emilie I checked the values of self.view, so I know for sure they differ from the mainWebView values. Also, if I just use 100x100 dimensions to assign to mainWebView, still nothing happens.

Comment: @Woodstock In the interface builer (I guess you mean Storyboard?) I gave the viewController size 'Inferred' (so that it works on every iOS device), the view 'Scale to Fill' and the WebView as also 'Scale to Fill' under view and then mode

Comment: did you set constraints for the UIWebView to the viewController?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the whole frame at once. Setting the size of a UIView's frame directly does not work.

```
var newRect = mainWebView.frame
newRect.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width
newRect.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height
mainWebView.frame = newRect
```